# How to write FindBugs detector of checking object closed

Tags: java, bytecode, findbugs

I'm new to FindBugs. I'm writing a customized FindBugs detector for such case:

```
GlobalObject ob = Global.open(String Id);
// Do some computation
Global.close(ob);
```

If there is an Exception thrown in the computation part, close statement will never reach and cause memory leak.

Correct way can be:

```
GlobalObject ob = Global.open(String Id);
Try {
//computation
}
Finally {
Global.close(ob);
}
```

or:

```
Try (SimilarAutoCloseable ob = new SimilarAutoCloseable(String Id)) {
// computation
}
```

I know OS_OPEN_STREAM FindBugs bug type seems similar. Though I don't know how to implement the detector extending BytecodeScanningDetector too much in detail. A similar example could be very helpful.

Comment: [1] Do not use FindBugs. Use its successor, [SpotBugs](https://spotbugs.github.io/) [2] It's not clear why you feel the need to write a custom detector. How would it differ from the four bug patterns already reported by SportBugs? (Search the page http://spotbugs.readthedocs.io/en/latest/bugDescriptions.html for occurrences of OS_OPEN_STREAM for details of them.)

Comment: Thanks. Bug pattern of OS_OPEN_STREAM is what I need. But I do need to some how "extend" it. I need it not only checking file stream, instead checking the specific type that we have, which I don't know how to do.

Comment: See the section titled "Implement SpotBugs plugin"on the [SpotBugs web site](http://spotbugs.readthedocs.io/en/latest/implement-plugin.html).